# Do we have $\Big(\int_a^b M(t)dt\Big)^{-1}= \int_a^b M^{-1} (t)dt$

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral, matrix-calculus

Let $M(t)\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a continuous mapping over $[0,T]$. And let us assume that $M(t)$ symmetric and positive-definite matrix for all $t\in [0,T]$.

Can we write the following :

$$\Big(\int_a^b M(t)dt\Big)^{-1}= \int_a^b M^{-1} (t)dt,$$
for every $a,b \in [0,T]$ ?

Comment: Probably not since inverses aren't linear function. Your best shot is to try consutrct a 2x2 counterexample where a well-known explicit formula for the inverse exists.

Comment: A simple counter-example: just take $a = b$ to see that it does not make sense.

Comment: Note that the left hand side has dimensions of $(M t)^{-1}$ while the right hand side has dimensions of $M^{-1} t$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Choose
$$
M(t) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\exp(t) & 0 \\
0 & \exp(t)
\end{pmatrix} \implies M(t)^{-1} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\exp(-t) & 0 \\
0 & \exp(-t)
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then
$$
\left( \int^b_a M(t)~\mathrm{d}t\right)^{-1} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{\exp(b)-\exp(a)} & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{\exp(b)-\exp(a)}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
\int^b_a M(t)^{-1}~\mathrm{d}t = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-\exp(-b)+\exp(-a)) & 0 \\
0 & -\exp(-b)+\exp(a)
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Different story though if inversion was a linear operator of matrices...

Answer (score 3):

It's probably hard to find cases where the equality does hold. You already have a counterexample if you take $M(t)=I _n$. Then
$$
\Big(\int_a^bM(t)\,dt\Big)^{-1}
=\frac1{b-a}\,I_n,
$$
while
$$
\int_a^bM(t)^{-1}\,dt=(b-a)\,I_n.
$$
So even with this trivial of trivials example the equality will fail as long as $b-a\ne\pm1$.

Answer (score 1):

This equality will simply not satisfy when the length $(b-a)$ and $det(M)(t)$ do not observe each other.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).